# Алгоритм Брезенхема для окружности

Tags: c, алгоритм, графика

Есть вот такая функция

```
void circle(HDC hdc, int x, int y)
{
//int x=0;
//int y=R;
int d=1-R;
int delta1=3;
int delta2=-2*R+5;

while(y>=0)
{
    if(d<0)
    {
        d+=delta1;
        delta1+=2;
        delta2+=2;
        x++;
    }
    else
    {
        d+=delta2;
        delta2+=4;
        delta1+=2;
        x++;
        y--;
    }
    SetPixel(hdc, x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

Она должна рисовать 1/8 окружности, но помимо этого рисуется еще и лишняя линия. Так вот как от нее избавиться?

Comment: Действительно, оказывается, есть алгоритм Брезенхема и для окружности :) . У них, кстати, там речь идёт про три варианта (вправо/по диагонали/вниз), у Вас только два. А R - достаточно большое? Больше 5?

Comment: @Михаил М R больше 5 и хочу в начале с этим вариантом разобраться.

Comment: @inham130, как Ваши успехи? Вы потрассировали, какие координаты точек получаются на выходе/поэкспериментировали с параметрами? По идее, должно быть понятно, что за алгоритм получился - он либо окружность рисует, либо линию

Comment: @Михаил М все получилось! Проблема была в моей невнимательности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стереть? :-) Или почитать в [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0) например. Мне почему-то кажется что SetPixel надо вызывать в начале а не в конце.